# fibonacci number's and euclid's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that given the integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ with $a \ge b$ and $b \lt F_n$, with $F_n$ the *n*-th Fibonacci number, using Euclid's algorithm it is possible to find $gcd(a,b)$ in less than *n* steps.

I've already proven that given $F_{n+2},F_{n+1}$ their *gcd* can be found in exactly *n* steps so it is simple to prove that if $F_n>a\ge b$; with $a = F_{n-1}$ and $b = f_{n-2}$ then $gcd(a,b)$ can be found in *n-1* steps, but I have to prove for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ not only for Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: There are several posts here to help you, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096929/how-to-find-number-of-steps-in-euclidean-algorithm-for-fibonacci-numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the number of steps needed for $\gcd(a, b)$ given $a\geq b$ is the same as the number of steps needed for $\gcd(a + kb, b)$ for *any natural number $k$*. You use a single step to get $\gcd(b, c)$ where $b\geq c$ regardless of how large $a$ might be.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive is easier to read and to prove:

> Let $a > b \ge 1$ be integers. If Euclid's algorithm takes at least $n$ steps to find $\gcd(a,b)$, then $a \ge F_{n+2}$ and $b \ge F_{n+1}$.

The proof is easy by induction. The key points are that all quotients are at least $1$ and the last one must be at least $2$. See for instance Chapter 31 of *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen–Leiserson–Rivest–Stein.